# Does ubuntu ever clear ~/.cache automatically?

Tags: cron, cache

I was wondering whether by default there's anything in place that clears the `.cache` folder. To my understanding `.cache` is similar to `/tmp`, at least I am seeing it being used like that.
Meaning that whatever is in either cache or temp might be reacessed at a certain point or even cleaned up and it shouldn't matter whether it's missing.

Comment: You might want to look into `BleachBit` that'll help you get rid of some unwanted cache and temp files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

It is your cache, so no specific global system process will interfere with it. File manager thumbnails, alt least in the default Ubuntu desktop, will be automatically deleted if they are more than 180 days around (as set by `org.gnome.desktop.thumbnail-cache maximum-age`) or when the cache exceeds 512 megabytes (as set by `org.gnome.desktop.thumbnail-cache maximum-size`). How other items in the cache are maintained or handled depends on the application maintaining the cache.

Answer (score 2):

`~/.cache` is not cleared automatically. Each individual application use `~/.cache` location to store its own cache data. If it is using more size, you can clear it according to application. If you clear/remove whole directory content, some applications which stored cache won't able to find cache and you might need to restart them. I would suggest to tune application cache for example you can control cache size for browser in browser settings.